# SQLite in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: sqlite, unreal-engine4

How can I interact with my own SQLite databases in Unreal Engine 4?
Can it be done via blueprint *and* C++ or would it have to be purely C++?

Comment: Try this: https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?49542-SQLite-3-Implementation-Into-Unreal-Engine-4 don't forget to read the whole threa.

Comment: Finding relevant UE documentation/tutorials on certain topics is frustrating at times.
If it works for me, can you put it as an answer so I can select it?
I'll comment when I'm done.

Comment: Release notes for Unreal Engine 4.6 indicate that a SQLiteSupport module has been added since my question was posted.
https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?53230-Unreal-Engine-4-6-Released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing SQLite from Unreal Engine can be done either from the blueprint (I haven't done it), but, check the TappyChicken blueprint example, the SaveGame class can store / load many variables through any event you want. Also here is a good video on YouTube:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0WRumU-gOk

In regards to the code, I use https://github.com/afuzzyllama/DataAccess. Try it out. It can save UObjects to a local database, sqlite.

For example:

```html
TSharedPtr<SqliteDataResource> DataResource = MakeShareable(new SqliteDataResource(FString(FPaths::GameDir() + "/Data/Test.db")));
DataResource->Acquire();
TSharedPtr<IDataHandler> DataHandler = MakeShareable(new SqliteDataHandler(DataResource));

UTestObject* TestObj = NewObject<UTestObject>();

// Create a record
DataHandler->Create(TestObj);

// Read a record
DatHandler->Read(/**record id*/ 1, TestObj);

// Update a record
TestObj->SomeProperty = "some value";
DataHandler->Update(TestObj);

// Delete a record
DataHandler->Delete(TestObj);

// This shouldn't be necessary since this should be run when the TSharedPtr runs out of references
DataResource->Release();
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the VaRest Plugin (blueprints available) which communicated to my server to handle to database entries, you might find this route easier.

https://wiki.unrealengine.com/VaRest_Plugin

Comment: This would be completely useless for SQLite, since SQLite is a "serverless" local database...